# Finding the name of a publishing journal for referencing

Tags: citations

The references for my PGDip need to follow the style of the  [Journal of Physics](http://ioppublishing.org/img/landingPages/guidelines-and-policies/author-guidelines.html) which states:

> A reference should give your reader enough information to locate the
>   article concerned and should consist of:

1. author name(s) and initials
2. year of publication
3. title of the journal or book
4. the volume number
5. for books: town of publication and the name of the publisher
6. and finally the article number or page numbers.

All I have are links, such as https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.06644v2 or http://adsabs.harvard.edu/doi/10.1086/175734. The authors and the publication year are obvious, but in the case of those links, how do I find the information about the journal they were published in? Are the arXiv links from the Journal of Physics?

Please excuse my ignorance, this is my first post-grad level report.

Answer (score 2):

ArXiv publications may be "self-standing"; if they are published in a journal somewhere, the journal citation information, including a link, is usually available on the "home" page for the paper.

The AdsAbs site has the citation information for the articles in the metadata: look for "Publication Journal."

And, of course, you could always use a site such as Google Scholar, Web of Science, or WorldCat to find the publication data you need.